# How can i write sql code to bring values from another table and use count function?

Tags: mysql, sql

My quesiton is :

Find the names of all classes that either meet in room R128 or have three or more students enrolled.

and my code is :

```
SELECT cname,count(cname) as total FROM lab5comblm258.enrolled 
where cname= any ( SELECT _name FROM lab5comblm258.class
WHERE room='R128' )
group by cname
;
```

[image]

What Must I add to my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` :

```
select cname
from lab5comblm258.enrolled  e
where exists (select 1 
              from lab5comblm258.class c 
              where c._name = e.cname and c.room = 'R128'
             )
group by cname
having count(*) >= 3;
```